# Convert ods to Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, ods

I am trying to convert an ods file to google sheets file format. However if the file is a little big (~ 2mb to 3mb) it starts to present the following problem several times

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with Internal Error

My code uses a try catcth to keep trying to convert. It can convert after many attempts or it doesn't even convert

```
var ssOrige = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId)
var ssOrigeBlob = ssOrige.getBlob()
var ssName = ssOrige.getName()

var newFile = {
    title : ssName.split('.')[0], 
    parents: [{id: folderDestinationId}]
  }
var ssDestination = null
while(!ssDestination) {
  try {
   // Cria cópia do arquivo como gSheet
   ssDestination = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, ssOrigeBlob, {convert: true})
  } catch (e) {
   Logger.log(e)
 }
}
```

Small files can have the same problem, but they tend to convert easier and faster

I have some ods files in a folder on the drive. I get the ods file by ID and try to convert it to google sheets format. I use Google App Script to get the file and try to do the conversion. So, I take an ods file that is already in the google drive and try to convert and save it inside the drive

Comment: In order to test and replicate your situation, can you provide a sample `ods file`?

Comment: Adding to @Tanaike request please try to explain what is exactly what are you doing. Is this being executed in node.js? Are you getting the file from a browser application with js?

Comment: @Raserhin  I have some ods files in a folder on the drive. I get the ods file by ID and try to convert it to google sheets format.

I use Google App Script to get the file and try to do the conversion.

So, I take an ods file that is already in the google drive and try to convert and save it inside the drive

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the [Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-sdk) try to use the [Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk).

Look at the [`Files.create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) and the section to upload new [Google Docs types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#import_to_google_docs_types).

This code is working fine for me with multiple files of various size:

```
function myFunction() {
  let id = "<YOUR ODS FILE ID>";
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);

  let fileBlob = file.getBlob();


  newFile = {
    name: "New File",
    mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  }

  try{
    Drive.Files.create(newFile, fileBlob);
  }catch(e){
    Logger.log("Error");
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```